# JavaScript - Google API lat/lng from country name

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wonder why this does not work, it perfectly logs `Object {lat: 52.132633, lng: 5.291265999999999}`. But only the `console.log()` inside the `done()` function works. To other one does not work, while I return that exact variable...

```
function getLatLng() {
    var LatLng;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=germany&sensor=false',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        LatLng = data.results[0];
        console.log(LatLng);
    })
    return LatLng;
}

console.log(getLatLng());
```

I need some workaround so that I can make the `initMap()` function work with my lattitude and longitude variables:

```
function getLatLng() {
    var LatLng;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=germany&sensor=false',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        LatLng = data.results[0];
        console.log(LatLng);
    })
    return LatLng;
}

console.log(getLatLng()); // undefined

  function initMap() {

    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
        [],
        {name: 'Styled Map'});

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: latVal, lng: lngVal}, // error >>> undefined
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain',
                'styled_map']
      }
    });

    map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
  }
```

Comment: Already tried `function findItem() {
    var item;
    while(item_not_found) {
        // search
    }
    return item;
}

var item = findItem();`

Comment: I updated my question, hopefully it is clearer now

Comment: This is because the `ajax.done()` Is executed after the return.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether I put the return out or inside the done function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the call to the google api is asynchronous.
This means the outer console log is executed while the response from google is still pending.

You could write it like this:

```
function getLatLng() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=germany&sensor=false',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
    });
}

getLatLng().done(function(data) {
    var latlng = data.results[0];
    console.log(latlng);
    //...further processing
});
```

If you need access to latlng outside the done function you could rewrite as so:

```
function getLatLngPromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=germany&sensor=false',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(data) {
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

async function getLatLng() {
    var data = await getLatLngPromise();
    return data[0];
}

var latlng = getLatLng();
console.log(latlng);
```

**Or you could parametrize the `initMap` with a latlng parameter and move the initMap call to the done function of my first example.** ([pastebin.com/VpSUma9R](https://pastebin.com/MvP2je9e))

Comment: I need access to it outside the done function

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: added an async example

Comment: Like so: https://pastebin.com/MvP2je9e ?

Comment: more like https://pastebin.com/VpSUma9R

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand the synchronisation order of JavaScript functions. Combined with an ajax call, it was quite confusing for me. Thank you anyways!

Comment: I now get this error very often: `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`. Not all the time, but more than regularly

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the full code as this error could be caused everywhere

Comment: Yes, never mind! I still got errors because I was still loading the maps api script `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` with the callback parameter `initMap()` I had to remove this, because now, I initialize `initMap()` manually! So everything works fine, big thanks to you.